# Let $f(x)=\delta(x) $ if $ x\in (-\infty,0] $ and $f(x)=0$ if $x\in (0,\infty)$. Then $I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx=?$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

Let $\delta$ be the Dirac delta function.

Then, let $f(x)=\delta(x) $ if $ x\in (-\infty,0]
$ and $f(x)=0$ if $x\in (0,\infty)$.Then $I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx=?$

Is $I=1/2$? We know $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(x)dx=1$. But we can not say that $\delta$ is symmetric about $y-axis$. So we can not conclude that $I=1/2$. Then what will be $I$?

Comment: What does it mean to define a distribution in this "pointwise" way?

Comment: Actually, during my study, I got an integration of Dirac delta function in the half of its domain (something like -1 to 0).

Answer (score 1):

1. OP is essentially describing an ill-defined product of two [distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics))$^1$
   $$ u~=~\theta \delta, $$
   where $\theta$ denotes the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) and $\delta$ is the [Dirac delta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function). Products of distributions is a well-known delicate topic, see e.g. [this](https://mathoverflow.net/q/48067) mathoverflow post and [Colombeau algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colombeau_algebra).

   To see what slippery slope lies ahead, consider the following ill-defined chains of formal manipulations:
   $$u~=~\theta \delta~=~\theta \theta^{\prime}~=~\frac{1}{2}(\theta^2)^{\prime}
   ~=~\frac{1}{2}\theta^{\prime}~=~\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}} \delta $$
   versus
   $$u~=~\theta \delta~=~\theta^2 \delta~=~\theta^2 \theta^{\prime}~=~\frac{1}{3}(\theta^3)^{\prime}
   ~=~\frac{1}{3}\theta^{\prime}~=~\color{red}{\frac{1}{3}} \delta~! $$
2. Later OP asks to evaluate the distribution $u[\varphi]$ for the constant function $\varphi=1$. Technically speaking, a constant function $\varphi=1$ is *not* a valid [test function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Test_functions_and_distributions).

--

$^1$ We consider in this answer the "mirror" distribution $\theta(x) \delta(x)$ rather than OP's distribution $\theta(-x) \delta(x)$ to simplify notation. The conceptional challenges will be the same.

Answer (score -1):

Since Delta is defined with $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$ you cannot change those limits. What you can do is construct test function as $\phi(x)=1$ if $x\in(-\infty,0]$ and $\phi(x)=0$ if $x\in(0,\infty)$ and ask what is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(x)\delta(x)dx$. The answer is obviously $\phi(0)=1$.

Comment: "The answer is obviously ϕ(0)=1" Why? The normal approximation to delta, for example, yields in the limit the result $\frac12$, it seems.

Comment: @Did because it's the definition of $\delta$. It always returns function's value at zero.

Comment: Only if they are continuous at $0$ (plus some conditions). Your $\phi$ is not.

Comment: @Did then you have to use something like this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colombeau_algebra

Comment: No. $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: @Did if you want to multiply generalized functions, which you do, there's no other way.